# POST 500 (Internal Server Error) Ajax Поиск

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с не понятной мною проблемой! Когда пытаюсь искать квартиры , то выдает ошибку `POST` `500 (Internal Server Error)`, но когда ищу отели , то все в порядке и нет ошибок

Логи сервера:

> [Fri May 12 12:52:29 2017] [error] [client 185.14.7.205] Directory
>   index forbidden by Options directive:
>   /var/www/mishatest/data/www/site.ru/images/catalog/tmb/, referer:
>   site.ru/articles/main/poisk-appartamentov
>
> [Fri May 12 12:52:29 2017] [error] [client 185.14.7.205] File does not exist: /var/www/mishatest/data/www/site.ru/js/lang, referer:
>   site.ru/articles/main/poisk-appartamentov
>
> [Fri May 12 12:52:29 2017] [error] [client 185.14.7.205] Directory index forbidden by Options directive:
>   /var/www/mishatest/data/www/site.ru/images/catalog/tmb/, referer:
>   site.ru/articles/main/poisk-appartamentov

Код поиска отелей

```
<? if ( $current == "/articles/main/hotels/" ) { ?>     


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" id="form_hotels" name="form_hotels">

<input type="hidden" name="poisk_otel" value="poisk_otel" />

<div class="cck_page_search">

<div id="cck1r" class="cck-simple search_otles form">

    <div class="position1">

    <span class="specpred">Специальные предложения!</span>

<table class="searchotels" cellpadding="0">


    <tr>
        <td class='searchotels_title'>Округ:</td>       
        <td class='searchotels_input_block'>
            <select id="district" name="district" class="inputbox select "  size="1" >
                <option value="" selected="selected">- Все округа -</option>
                <? foreach ( $district as $item ) { ?>              
                    <option value="<?=$item["id"];?>"><?=$item["name"];?></option>                  
                <? } ?>
            </select>
        </td>       

        <td class='searchotels_title'>Город:</td>       
        <td class='searchotels_input_block'>
            <select id="city" name="city" class="inputbox select "  size="1" >
                <option value="" selected="selected">- Все города -</option>
                <? foreach ( $city as $item ) { ?>              
                    <option value="<?=$item["id"];?>"><?=$item["name"];?></option>                  
                <? } ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td class='searchotels_title'>Название отеля:</td>
        <td class='searchotels_input_block searchotels_input_block_text'>       
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" class="inputbox text " size="32" />
        </td>
        <td class='searchotels_title'>Уровень:</td>
        <td class='searchotels_input_block'>        
            <select id="level" name="level" class="inputbox select " size="1" >
                <option value="" selected="selected">- Все уровни -</option>
                <? foreach ( $level as $item ) { ?>             
                    <option value="<?=$item["id"];?>"><?=$item["name"];?></option>                  
                <? } ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" align="right">
            <div class="greenbuttonsearch">
                <input type="submit" id="search_hotels" name="search_hotels" value="Подобрать" class="button " />            </div>
            <div class='cl'></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

    </div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>

</form>


<table class="appartaments_result" id="tabl">               
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>


<script>
    $('body').on('click', '#search_hotels', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();            

        $.ajax({
            url: "/index/index/",
            type: "post",
            data: $('#form_hotels').serialize(),                
            global: false,
            dataType: "json",
            response:'text',
            cache: false, 
            async: false,
            success: function(data) { 

                $('#del').remove();

                for ( var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {

                    var img = '';
                    for ( var j=0; j<data[i].id_level; j++ ) {                      
                        if ( j<5 ) { img = img + '<img src="/images/star.png" alt="Star" />'; } else {
                                     img = img + '<strong style="font-size:18px;"> DLX</strong>'; break; }                          
                    }  

                    var strPost = '<tr>'
                        +'<td>'
                            +'<a href="/catalog/oteli/'+data[i].alias+'">'
                                +'<img src="/images/catalog/tmb/'+data[i].preview+'" alt="" width="193" height="147" />'
                            +'</a>'
                        +'</td>'
                        +'<td valign="top" style="padding-left: 16px;">'
                            +'<div class="ar_levels">'+img+'</div>'
                            +'<div class="ar_title">'
                                +'<a href="/catalog/oteli/'+data[i].alias+'">'+data[i].name+'</a>'
                            +'</div>'
                            +'<div class="ar_desc">'+data[i].textarea.substr(0,232)+'...</div>'
                            +'<div class="ar_more">'
                                +'<a href="/catalog/oteli/'+data[i].alias+'">Подробнее &gt;</a>'
                            +'</div>'
                        +'</td>'
                    +'</tr>';                               

                    $('#tabl > tbody').append(strPost);

                }

            }

        });         
    }); 
</script>



        <? if ( isset($hotels) && !empty($hotels) ) { ?>
            <table class="appartaments_result" id="del">
                <? foreach ( $hotels as $otel ) { ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/catalog/oteli/<?=$otel["alias"];?>">
                                <img src="/images/catalog/tmb/<?=$otel["preview"];?>" alt="" width="193" height="147" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 16px;">
                            <div class="ar_levels">
                                <? for ( $i=1; $i<=$otel["id_level"]; $i++ ) { ?>
                                    <? if ( $i<=5 ) { ?>
                                        <img src="/images/star.png" alt="Star" />
                                    <? } else { ?>
                                        <strong style="font-size:18px;"> DLX</strong>
                                    <? break; } ?>
                                <? } ?>                         
                            </div>
                            <div class="ar_title">
                                <a href="/catalog/oteli/<?=$otel["alias"];?>"><?=$otel["name"];?></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ar_desc"><?=mb_substr($otel["textarea"],0,232,'UTF-8');?>...</div>
                            <div class="ar_more">
                                <a href="/catalog/oteli/<?=$otel["alias"];?>">Подробнее &gt;</a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                <? } ?>
            </table>
        <? } ?>



<? } ?> 

<table class="appartaments_result" id="tabl"><tbody></tbody></table>

<script>
    $('body').on('click', '#search_appartament', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 

        $.ajax({
            url: "/index/index/",
            type: "post",
            data: $('#form_appartament').serialize(),               
            global: false,
            dataType: "json",
            response:'text',
            cache: false, 
            async: false,
            success: function(data) { 

                //$('#del').remove();

                alert( data );

                for ( var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {

                    var img = '';
                    for ( var j=0; j<data[i].id_level; j++ ) {                      
                        if ( j<5 ) { img = img + '<img src="/images/star.png" alt="Star" />'; } else {
                                     img = img + '<strong style="font-size:18px;"> DLX</strong>'; break; }                          
                    }  

                    var strPost = '<tr>'
                        +'<td>'
                            +'<a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/'+data[i].alias+'">'
                                +'<img src="/images/catalog/tmb/'+data[i].preview+'" alt="" width="193" height="147" />'
                            +'</a>'
                        +'</td>'
                        +'<td valign="top" style="padding-left: 16px;">'
                            +'<div class="ar_levels">'+img+'</div>'
                            +'<div class="ar_title">'
                                +'<a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/'+data[i].alias+'">'+data[i].name+'</a>'
                            +'</div>'
                            +'<div class="ar_desc">'+data[i].textarea.substr(0,232)+'...</div>'
                            +'<div class="ar_more">'
                                +'<a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/'+data[i].alias+'">Подробнее &gt;</a>'
                            +'</div>'
                        +'</td>'
                    +'</tr>';                               

                    $('#tabl > tbody').append(strPost);

                }

            }

        });         
    }); 
</script>
```

Код поиска квартир

```
<? if ( $current == "/articles/main/poisk-appartamentov/" ) { ?>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" id="form_appartament" name="form_appartament">

    <input type="hidden" name="poisk_appartament" value="poisk_appartament" />

    <div class="cck_page_search">
    <div id="cck1r" class="cck-simple search_appartaments form">
    <div class="position1">

        <span class="specpred">Специальные предложения!</span>

        <table class="search_apartaments_table">
            <tr>            
                <td class='search_apartaments_area'>
                    <select id="district" name="district" class="inputbox select "  size="1" >                  
                        <option value="" selected="selected">- Все округа -</option>
                        <? foreach ( $district as $item ) { ?>              
                            <option value="<?=$item["id"];?>"><?=$item["name"];?></option>                  
                        <? } ?>                 
                    </select>
                </td>               
                <td class="search_apartaments_city">                    
                    <select id="city" name="city" class="inputbox select "  size="1" >
                        <option value="" selected="selected">- Все города -</option>
                        <? foreach ( $city as $item ) { ?>              
                            <option value="<?=$item["id"];?>"><?=$item["name"];?></option>                  
                        <? } ?>
                    </select>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='search_apartaments_type'>                
                    <select id="type_nedvizh" name="type_nedvizh" class="inputbox select "  size="1" >
                        <option value="" selected="selected">- Любой тип недвижимости -</option>
                        <? foreach ( $type_nedvizh as $item ) { ?>              
                            <option value="<?=$item["id"];?>"><?=$item["name"];?></option>                  
                        <? } ?>
                    </select>               
                </td>


                <script type="text/javascript">
                            var cal = Calendar.setup({
                                trigger     : "ot_hidden-trigger",
                                inputField  : "ot_hidden",
                                dateFormat  : "%d/%m/%Y",
                                weekNumbers : false,
                                timePos     : "right",  
                                showTime    : false,                        
                                min         : 20170119, 
                                onSelect    : function(cal) { 
                                        var sel_date = this.selection.get();
                                        var hours   =   cal.getHours();
                                        var minutes =   cal.getMinutes();
                                        var sel_date = Calendar.intToDate(sel_date);
                                        sel_date.setHours(hours);
                                        sel_date.setMinutes(minutes);var Jdate = Calendar.printDate(sel_date, "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00");$j("#ot").val(Jdate) ;this.hide(); }});
                </script>


                <td class="datepicker">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class='datepicker_from'>От&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class='datepicker_from_block'>
                                <input class="inputbox text " type="text" id="ot_hidden" name="ot_hidden" readonly="readonly" maxlength="255" size="27" value=""  /><input class="inputbox" type="hidden" id="ot" name="ot" value="" /><img src="/images/calendar.png" alt="Calendar" class="calendar" id="ot_hidden-trigger" />



                        <div class='cl'></div>
                            </td>
                            <td class='datepicker_to' align="right">До&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class='datepicker_to_block'>
                                <input class="inputbox text " type="text" id="do_hidden" name="do_hidden" readonly="readonly" maxlength="255" size="27" value=""  /><input class="inputbox" type="hidden" id="do" name="do" value="" /><img src="/images/calendar.png" alt="Calendar" class="calendar" id="do_hidden-trigger" />
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            var cal = Calendar.setup({
                                trigger     : "do_hidden-trigger",
                                inputField  : "do_hidden",
                                dateFormat  : "%d/%m/%Y",
                                weekNumbers : false,                        
                                timePos     : "right",  
                                showTime    : false,                        
                                min         : 20170119, 
                                onSelect    : function(cal) { 
                                        var sel_date = this.selection.get();
                                        var hours   =   cal.getHours();
                                        var minutes =   cal.getMinutes();
                                        var sel_date = Calendar.intToDate(sel_date);
                                        sel_date.setHours(hours);
                                        sel_date.setMinutes(minutes);var Jdate = Calendar.printDate(sel_date, "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00");$j("#do").val(Jdate) ;this.hide(); }});
                        </script>
                        <div class='cl'></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='search_apartaments_type'>
            <select id="count_guest" name="count_guest" class="inputbox select " size="1" >
                <option value="" selected="selected">- Количество гостей -</option>
                <option value="02">1-2</option>
                <option value="03">1-3</option>
                <option value="04">1-4</option>
                <option value="05">1-5</option>
                <option value="06">1-6</option>
                <option value="07">1-7</option>
                <option value="08">1-8</option>
                <option value="09">1-9</option>
                <option value="10">1-10</option>
                <option value="11">10+</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            <td class="search_apartaments_price">           
                <select id="interval_price" name="interval_price" class="inputbox select "  size="1" >
                    <option value="" selected="selected">- Ценовые рамки -</option>
                    <? foreach ( $interval_price as $item ) { ?>                
                        <option value="<?=$item["id"];?>"><?=$item["name"];?></option>                  
                    <? } ?>
                </select>       
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="search_apartaments_count">
                <select id="count_root" name="count_root" class="inputbox select " size="1" >
                    <option value="" selected="selected">- Количество комнат -</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="12+">12+</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="r"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%" valign="bottom"><span>                  
                        <input type="hidden" name="kosher" value="0">
                        <input name="kosher" value="1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                    </span> Кошер</td>
                <tr>
                </tr>
                    <td width="50%" valign="bottom"><span>

                    <input type="hidden" name="osobenniy" value="0">
                    <input name="osobenniy" value="1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                    </span> <img src="/images/inv.png" alt="" /></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"><div class="greenbuttonsearch">
                <input type="submit" id="search_appartament" name="search_appartament" value="Подобрать" class="button"/>
            </div></td>
        </tr>
        </table>        
    </div>              
    </div>
    </div>      
    </form>     

<table class="appartaments_result" id="tabl"><tbody></tbody></table>

<script>
    $('body').on('click', '#search_appartament', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 

        $.ajax({
            url: "/index/index/",
            type: "post",
            data: $('#form_appartament').serialize(),               
            global: false,
            dataType: "json",
            response:'text',
            cache: false, 
            async: false,
            success: function(data) { 

                //$('#del').remove();

                alert( data );

                for ( var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {

                    var img = '';
                    for ( var j=0; j<data[i].id_level; j++ ) {                      
                        if ( j<5 ) { img = img + '<img src="/images/star.png" alt="Star" />'; } else {
                                     img = img + '<strong style="font-size:18px;"> DLX</strong>'; break; }                          
                    }  

                    var strPost = '<tr>'
                        +'<td>'
                            +'<a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/'+data[i].alias+'">'
                                +'<img src="/images/catalog/tmb/'+data[i].preview+'" alt="" width="193" height="147" />'
                            +'</a>'
                        +'</td>'
                        +'<td valign="top" style="padding-left: 16px;">'
                            +'<div class="ar_levels">'+img+'</div>'
                            +'<div class="ar_title">'
                                +'<a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/'+data[i].alias+'">'+data[i].name+'</a>'
                            +'</div>'
                            +'<div class="ar_desc">'+data[i].textarea.substr(0,232)+'...</div>'
                            +'<div class="ar_more">'
                                +'<a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/'+data[i].alias+'">Подробнее &gt;</a>'
                            +'</div>'
                        +'</td>'
                    +'</tr>';                               

                    $('#tabl > tbody').append(strPost);

                }

            }

        });         
    }); 
</script>   



        <? if ( isset($nedvizhimost) && !empty($nedvizhimost) ) { ?>
            <table class="appartaments_result">
                <? foreach ( $nedvizhimost as $kvartira ) { ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/<?=$kvartira["alias"];?>">
                                <img src="/images/catalog/tmb/<?=$kvartira["preview"];?>" alt="" width="193" height="147" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 16px;">
                            <div class="ar_levels">
                                <? for ( $i=1; $i<=$kvartira["id_level"]; $i++ ) { ?>

                                    <? if ( $i<=5 ) { ?>
                                        <img src="/images/star.png" alt="Star" />
                                    <? } else { ?>
                                        <strong style="font-size:18px;"> DLX</strong>
                                    <? } ?>

                                <? } ?>                         
                            </div>
                            <div class="ar_title">
                                <a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/<?=$kvartira["alias"];?>"><?=$kvartira["name"];?></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ar_desc"><?=$kvartira ["textarea"];?></div>
                            <div class="ar_more">
                                <a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/<?=$kvartira["alias"];?>">Подробнее &gt;</a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                <? } ?>
            </table>
        <? } ?>




<? } ?>
```

Comment: так вроде же написанно forbidden - доступ запрещён

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте в настройках .htaccess или конфигах сервера директиву Options, в логах пишется, что именно из-за этого запрещен доступ в директорию.